# Add new database user in homestead.yaml

Tags: laravel, homestead

I've specified a second database in my `homestead.yaml` file and this gets created without a hitch, but it uses the default `homestead` database user.

Is it possible to also include a new user in `homestead.yaml`, or is this something I just need to do manually after the vagrant instance is up and running? I didn't notice anything in the docs about this.

It's a Postgres database if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this from the yaml file. Alternatively you can write the commands to create the user in **after.sh** file inside the .homestead folder. This way after the virtual machine is created, it will get executed  automatically and your new user will be ready, without you doing it manually.

Comment: Thanks @Sameer, I thought that might be the case. Do you think it'd be better to both create the database and user in `after.sh` in that case? It seems a bit wrong to create the database in one place and the user separately somewhere else. I realise it probably doesn't matter, but I was thinking in terms of best practice. As I'm new to Laravel and I'd rather start out on the right path.

Comment: I prefer creating the DB as well as USER in `after.sh` , that way it is in one place and not confusing.